# Is it possible to hook System methods in .NET Core?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I'd like to hook (preferably at runtime) C# System methods.

For example, I'd like to print the method name and its arguments once its invoked.
Take "System.IO.File.WriteAllText()" for example, I'd like to print it's name and be able to return a different response.

I can't find any up to date information about it.

Thanks

Comment: i think this is what you are after https://www.encora.com/insights/aspect-oriented-programming-aop-in-.net-core-and-c-using-autofac-and-dynamicproxy

Comment: Other than creating a wrapper class which calls those System methods I cannot think of a way.  I know this isn't very useful :(  This is one reason why I always wrap calls to System methods in another class within my projects.

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/articles/15410/creating-a-custom-net-profiler

Comment: Thanks @HansPassant but this is from 2006 and not for .NET Core

Comment: Thanks @pm100 but this requires method decoration which can't be done on System classes.

Comment: I know we did something with castle dynamic proxy to achieve what you are after, maybe not exactly like the article i pointed at. Poke at it a bit - sorry I cant recall details

Comment: The profiler interface [has not fundamentally changed](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/coreclr/pal/prebuilt/inc/corprof.h) in .netcore, the article demonstrates the approach you need to take.  If you give up this quick without researching the solution then just assume everybody else is accurate and it is not possible.

Comment: Unfortunately this is an external profiler process, I'm looking to hook at runtime from the C# code itself